# element.animate('margin-left', value) working with Chrome not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

If I run this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWbFw/172/) with Chrome, by pressing the divs or the tabs the animation on the "wrapper" divs works smoothly. If you run it with Firefox it doesn't work. What I've been reading is that animate('margin-left', value) should be replace it for Firefox with animate('left', value) but this is not a option because the animation with margin-left is on the div who contains the "tabs" divs and the animation with left is on the "tabs" divs.

Any idea on how can I simulate this behaviour?

Constraints:

Chrome Version: 19.0.1084.56 m

Firefox Version:13

Jquery version: 1.3.2

Updating jquery is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `margin-left` to `marginLeft` - http://jsfiddle.net/rWbFw/173/

Comment: Omg! well thanks! Any explanation of why these differences? thanks very helpful